# Function signatures to reduce borrow checker problems

Tags: rust

I am learning Rust wondering how to model a certain problem. Let's assume I have some amount of persons with several attributes modeled as a struct.

```
struct Person {
        available_days: Vec<bool> // [0]=Monday .. [6]=Sunday
        possible_roles: Vec<Role>
        preferred_role: Role
        in_group: bool
        ... (quite a few more)
```

I'd like to build groups but have to fulfill requirements. E. g. certain amount of roles have to be present in each group, they have to be available on the same day and so on. I tried this signature:

```
fn build_group(avail_persons: &mut Vec<Person>) -> Option<Group> {...}
```

The idea of this signature is to get a a reference to a vector of preselected persons and try to find a good group setup.

The function calling build_group would do something like this:

```
let mut avail_day = persons
        .iter()
        .filter(|d|d.available_days[0] == 1) // all persons avialable on Monday
        .collect::Vec<&Person>>();
```

This creates a `Vec<&Person>` and I cannot create a `Vec<Person>` (missing copy trait).
A solution would be to change the signature of build_group to take a `Vec<&Person>` but that means I run into difficulties changing the person, e. g. person.in_group = true. After changing to Vec<&Person> I constantly run into problems with the borrow checker.

I have the impression I am fundamentally modeling the problem in a non-rust-friendly-way.

Is there any advice? Maybe a link to a github repo that handles this kind of problems. I'd like to read Rust code from experienced people anyway. I hope I was able to describe the problem good enough.

Comment: What is the type of `persons`? Why does `build_group()` accept a mutable reference to `Vec<Person>`, is it expected to change the contents of the `Vec`? Can you provide a more complete snippet?

Comment: It might be easier to model a group using the indices of the persons in the original vec. For example: `let avail_day = persons.iter().enumerate().filter_map (|(i, p)| if p.available_days[0] { Some (i) } else { None }).collect::<Vec<usize>>();`

Comment: If a `Person` can be copied, then cloning instances to add to `Group` is possible without borrow checker problems. However, if `Person` has state that needs to be updated in other places and accessible as a single instance, you'll need to look into smart pointers for mutable shared access. These classes include `Rc` and `RefCell` for single threaded access.

Answer (score 0):

If `persons` is a `Vec` and you're not going to need it anymore after filtering it, you can do this:

```
let mut avail_day = persons.retain(|d| d.available_days[0] == 1); // all persons avialable on Monday
```

[`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) "retains only the elements specified by the predicate".

If you are gonna need to use the other `Person`s, you can partition the `Vec` into two collections:

```
let (mut avail_day, unavail_day): (Vec<Person>, Vec<Person>) = persons
        .into_iter()
      // ^^^^^ note the "into" here
        .partition(|d| d.available_days[0] == 1); // all persons avialable on Monday
```

`into_iter` takes the `Vec` by value, instead of by reference, and allows you to collect it into values again.

By the way, in Rust it's preferred to take a slice instead of a `Vec` if you take your argument by reference, i.e. the signature should be

```
fn build_group(avail_persons: &mut [Person]) -> Option<Group> {...}
```

This way you can pass in anything that can be converted to a slice (like `Vec`s).